# Unable to run psql command inside a postgres docker container

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, containers

I have recently started using Docker. However, while I was able to run a postgres container and run a bash command "psql" inside it. Now, I am facing error in trying to do the same after sometime.
Here is what worked for me sometime back and now it does not work anymore:

**docker run --rm -it postgres bash**

The above command opens a bash inside the postgres container. When I type psql inside this container, it shows error:

root@3615146cf679:/# **psql**

psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket “/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432”?

Comment: Can you use `psql` from the host, using the port you published out of the container to access it?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use these commands in order:
start the container with:

```
$ sudo docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -d postgres
```

enter the container with:

```
$ sudo docker exec -it some-postgres /bin/bash
```

when you entered the container, run:

```
$ psql -U postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

I myself figured it out that using "bash" at the time of starting the container was causing the problem. Once we run it using:

```
docker run --rm postgres
```

Above command says that we need to provide a Password or Auth Method. Hence, we do so.
Anyone of below 3 commands can start a postgres container:

```
docker run --rm -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres
```

or

```
docker run --rm -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres
```

or

```
docker run --rm -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e 
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres postgres
```

Then, we can execute:

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
psql -U postgres
CREATE TABLE tutorials (id int, tutorial_name text);
INSERT INTO tutorials VALUES (1, 'C++');
select * from tutorials;
```